# How can I implement a consumer-producer problem?

Tags: asynchronous-processing

I want to implement [consumer-producer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) in *Mathematica*.

Example: I want 2 threads/processes:

1st: Get data from Twitter's API by doing multiple requests. After each request, I want to send the response(tweets) to the 2nd process.

2nd: Do something with the tweets received from the other process(e.g. print, analyse or whatever)

PS: I'm new to *Mathematica*.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)